# Required HLB on the Griffin Scale

Tags: reaction-mechanism

What is the required HLB on the Griffin Scale of 94% water and 6% mineral oil for producing a stable micro-emulsion?

Answer (score 0):

The required HLB doesn't depend on the concentration of water. The required HLB of mineral oil is ca. from 9 to 12. You have to find out the required HLB of your mineral oil at first.